# file.encoding has no effect, LC_ALL environment variable does it

Tags: java, linux, file, encoding, internationalization

In the following Java program running in Linux using OpenJDK 1.6.0_22 I simply list the contents of the directory taken in as parameter at the command line. The directory contains the files which have file names in UTF-8 (e.g. Hindi, Mandarin, German etc.).

```
import java.io.*;

class ListDir {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //System.setProperty("file.encoding", "en_US.UTF-8");
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
    File f = new File(args[0]);
    for(String c : f.list()) {
        String absPath = args[0] + "" + c;
        File cf = new File(args[0] + "/" + c);
        System.out.println(cf.getAbsolutePath() + " --> " + cf.exists());
    }
    }
}
```

If I set the LC_ALL variable to en_US.UTF-8 the results are printed fine. But if I set the LC_ALL variable to POSIX and supply the file.encoding and sun.jnu.encoding properties as UTF-8 from command line I get the garbage output and cf.exists() returns false.

Can you please explain this behavior. As I read on so many websites file.encoding is said to be sufficient to read file names and use them for operations. Here it looks like that property has no effect at all.

**Update 1:** If I set file.encoding to something like GBK (Chinese) and LC_ALL variable to en_US.UTF-8 then cf.exists() returns true. only the '?' appears instead of file name. Surprise o_O.

**Update 2:** More investigation and it looks like its not a Java issue. It looks like libc on Linux used locale settings to translate file name encodings and those settings will cause file not found error/exception. "file.encoding" is for how Java interprets file names.

**Update 3** Now it looks problem is how Java interprets file names. The following simple C code works on Linux regardless of file encoding and value of LC_ALL environment variable (I am happy that this proves for answer given here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39175/understanding-unix-file-name-encoding). But still I am not clear how Java interprets on LC_ALL variable. Now looking into OpenJDK code for that.

Sample C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *argdir = argv[1];
    DIR *dp = opendir(argdir);
    struct dirent *de;
    while(de = readdir(dp)) {
        char *abspath = (char *) malloc(strlen(argdir)  + 1 + strlen(de->d_name) + 1);
        strcpy(abspath, argdir);
        abspath[strlen(argdir)] = '/';
        strcpy(abspath + strlen(argdir) + 1, de->d_name);
        printf("%d %s ", de->d_type, abspath);
        FILE *fp = fopen(abspath, "r");
        if (fp) {
            printf("Success");
        }
        fclose(fp);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure who exactly is responsible for decoding the command line arguments. Could be the shell, could be Java. Does it work as expected if you get the file name from somewhere else (String literal, or reading from stdin, or from a properties file)?

Comment: Why are you doing the `absPath` dance? Just for demonstration purposes here? You can do f.listFiles() instead of f.list() to get File objects directly (that presumably work).

Comment: @Thilo Its just a sample program.

Comment: @Thilo: It appears that the `sun.jnu.encoding` mentioned in the question affects command line interpretation. In a `LC_CTYPE=POSIX` setup but with a UTF-8 terminal, if I pass `-Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8`, the a non-ASCII character from a command line argument gets printed as a single `?` even when it is two bytes. If I pass `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`, too, then it gets printed as UTF-8 as well. If I only pass the latter, then I get two unicode unavailable symbol glyphs printed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Note: So finally I think that I have nailed it down. I am not confirming that it is right. But with some code reading and tests this is what I found out and I don't have additional time to look into it. If anyone is interested they can check it out and tell if this answer is right or wrong - I would be glad :)*

The reference I used was from this tarball available at OpenJDK's site: 
**openjdk-6-src-b25-01_may_2012.tar.gz**

1. Java natively translates all string to platform's local encoding in this method: `jdk/src/share/native/common/jni_util.c - JNU_GetStringPlatformChars()` . System property `sun.jnu.encoding` is used to determine the platform's encoding.
2. The value of `sun.jnu.encoding` is set at `jdk/src/solaris/native/java/lang/java_props_md.c - GetJavaProperties()` using `setlocale()` method of libc. Environment variable `LC_ALL` is used to set the value of `sun.jnu.encoding`. Value given at the command prompt using `-Dsun.jnu.encoding` option to Java is ignored.
3. Call to `File.exists()` has been coded in file `jdk/src/share/classes/java/io/File.java` and it returns as

   `return ((fs.getBooleanAttributes(this) & FileSystem.BA_EXISTS) != 0);`
4. `getBooleanAttributes()` is natively coded (and I am skipping steps in code browsing through many files) in `jdk/src/share/native/java/io/UnixFileSystem_md.c` in function :
   `Java_java_io_UnixFileSystem_getBooleanAttributes0()`. Here the macro 
   `WITH_FIELD_PLATFORM_STRING(env, file, ids.path, path)` converts path string to platform's encoding.
5. So conversion to wrong encoding will actually send a wrong C string (char array) to subsequent call to `stat()` method. And it will return with result that file cannot be found.

**LESSON:** `LC_ALL` is very important

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure where you read about `file.encoding`. I don't see it mentioned with the other [standard properties as documented with `System.getProperties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29). But judging from my experiments, it seems that this value influences the encoding of file *content*, not file *names*. `System.out` in particular will not print non-ASCII characters if `file.encoding` is `POSIX`.

On the other hand, the Linux way to decide which encoding applies to file names is the `LC_CTYPE` facet of the current locale setting. I see no reason why Java should override this. As many other platforms (Windows in particular) always use Unicode for file names, not bytes, there is little point in exposing the byte-level details of the file system to a Java application.

Comment: Thanks:) Additional link: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzaha%2Fcharenc.htm

Comment: File names are (in the Oracle and OpenJDK JVMS) affected by the "sun.jnu.encoding" property. See http://happygiraffe.net/blog/2009/09/24/java-platform-encoding/

Answer (score 2):

Please see [bug 4163515](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4163515) at java.com. It explains that:

1. file.encoding is specific to Sun (now Oracle) implementation of JVM - others may not support it
2. Shall be considered read-only
3. To change it you shall modify environment in which the JVM runs (which is what you did with LC_ALL)

Also note that even if changing file.encoding "works" for your platform, you shall not do that - as it does not change default encoding used by Oracle JVM in general, but only in some subsystems. As the bug shows default encoding used by String constructors taking byte arrays are unaffected by this setting.